# How do I properly wrap code with matching pairs in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

So I'm pretty sure I'm using autopairs like a newb in IntelliJ.

Let's say I want to change this:

`$!processed-content.process.embed-youtube;`

to this:

`$!processed-content.process(embed-youtube);`

What I do is delete the last `.` and then insert a `(` and the second one gets generated. So now I have this:

`$!processed-content.process()embed-youtube;`

So then I have to delete the second paren manually, jump to the semi and insert it.

Is there a way to move the `embed-youtube` bit into the parens more quickly?

Comment: delete dot, then highlight `embed-youtube` using ctrl+right, then hit `(` to wrap the highlighted into parens

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. When I try to insert the paren, the cursor just jumps several characters to the right. I forgot to mention of I have the idea vim plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IdeaVim, you can use the emulated [surround](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/wiki/IdeaVim-Plugins#surround) plugin. After enabling, you can navigate to the word to wrap, then use `ysiw)`. Alternatively, you can visually select the text and then use `S)`.

Assuming your cursor is at '*': `$!processed-content.process.*embed-youtube;`

You could use `vt;S)` (mnemonic: visual to ';' Surround bracket).